# Traversing JSON tree with variable value instead of literal not working using NodeJS

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I am trying to pull data from a online API in JSON format as abstractly as possible.

I have code in the exact same structure as this:

```
require("request")

var url = ""//Myurl

request({
url: url,
json: true
}, function (error, response, body) {

if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
    console.log(body) 
}
})
```

And I have a JSON like this:

```
    { John:
       { ID: 1212,
         Age: 12
       }
    }
```

I want to refer to "John" using this way

```
      var tempName = "John";//not limited to it being in the same scope
      console.log(body.tempName.ID);
```

instead of going this way

```
      console.log(body.John.ID);
```

to access his ID.

I have tried using for each on the body response to get the name and then access it through that, but I couldn't get that right.

Comment: Have you tried `body[tempName].ID;`?

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

`console.log(body[tempName].ID);`

This will point your `body` object to value of the variable `tempName` instead of the name of the variable.